# Why Saml is the default option for registering Salesforce as an Enterprise Application is AAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, salesforce, single-sign-on, openid-connect, saml

I am trying to integrate Salesforce with AAD, so I see two available options, either Saml or OpenId Connect.. I do not know which one is better, but I prefer OpenId Connect since it seems to be more modern. So I tried to register Salesforce App in AAD and Saml was the default options, so why is Saml the default option ?! is it better or what? Please note that I am building an API and I need to allow authentication and authorization with Single Sign On.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure AD app gallery contains many popular applications that are already pre-configured to work with Azure AD as an identity provider. These applications will be available in the Enterprise applications and have SAML to perform SSO. Any application which is added directly from the Gallery the default method is SAML based SSO , password based SSO etc.. which depends upon the applications.

Kindly check the difference between the App Registration and Gallery application in Azure portal from the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/cde6dfc0-ba30-4cd7-8b0a-7420afb3bcff/difference-between-azure-ad-app-registration-and-enterprise-application?forum=WindowsAzureAD)

In order to get more detailed explanation about SSO types and protocols kindly check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-howto-app-gallery-listing) to get more detailed explanation.

If you have any further queries kindly let me know.